# Extracting a point from ggplot and plot it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am initially having the dataset as shown below:

```
ID  A    B  Type  Time  Date
1  12    13   R  23:20 1-1-01
1  13    12   F  23:40 1-1-01
1  13    11   F  00:00 2-1-01
1  15    10   R  00:20 2-1-01
1  12    06   W  00:40 2-1-01
1  11    09   F  01:00 2-1-01
1  12    10   R  01:20 2-1-01
so on...
```

I tried to make the ggplot of the above dataset for A and B.

```
ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=A, y=B, colour = Type)) +geom_point()+geom_path()
```

**Problem:**

1. HOW do I add a subsetting variable that looks at the first 24 hours after the every 'F' point.
2. For the time being I have posted a continuous data set [with respect to time]  but my original data set is not continuous. How can I make my data set continuous in a interval of 10 mins? I have used interpolation xspline() function on A and B but I don't know how to make my data set continuous with respect to time,

The highlighted part shown below is what I am looking for, I want to extract this dataset and then plot a new ggplot:

[image]

**From MarkusN plots this is what I am looking for:**

**Taking first point as 'F' point and traveling 24hrs from that point (Since there is no 24 hrs data set available here so it should produce like this) :**

[image]

Comment: you want to plot A vs B or do you want to plot A and B vs time?

Comment: @SarinaJ. yes. I want to add time factor in my ggplot. Also I want to do the said problem. (Taking 'F' as starting point and draw another ggplot for next 24 hrs.)

Comment: Still straggling to understand the desired output. Do you want just a subset of your data set as a result or you want to add a layer on top of what you already have. Can we get some indication of the desired result?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I want a new plot, which is time dependent and should starts from where "F" point is present. The start point is the "F" point and the end point would be after 24 hrs. Which means that my new plot consist of one day dataset starting from the "F".

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have updated the question. Hope its clear now

Comment: @SarinaJ. I have updated the question by adding a sample ggplot. Can you review the question now

Comment: Really it just looks like you need to subset your data. Replace `dataframe` with `dataframe[dataframe$Type == "F",]` for example.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Yes, it is subsetting of data. But I am having a huge data set which consist of multiple "F" points in it. So for each "F" point i want to do the same.

Comment: So add another subsetting condition? `&`

Comment: I think I understand your question to be. HOW do I add a subsetting variable that looks at the first 24 hours after the first F. So in the case ahead, you want to plot only F 23:04 to the next F 23:04. Is that it?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen You got the question nearly right. But I want to just plot for the next 24 hrs. after the "F". and its not just first "F", for all the "F's" which are coming in the dataset. In this dataset there are 3 F's. So I want to plot for every "F" to the next 24 hrs.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I have added the highlights in my map to make it more understandable? Can you please review it again?

Comment: We need some kind of "day" variable. Right now, your times cross over a day but we don't know if they are continuous. With a day variable, you could convert to `as.POSIXlt` and then use `difftime()` to create a new variable on the subset of "F".

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Exactly. My dataset is not continuous. For now I have given the continuous data to make it easy. Can you give me some code for it?

Comment: There is no code if you don't have some type of date variable. Without a date we can't identify a 24 hour time frame that crosses a day.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen you can assume the date. I have updated the question & write some dates there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created sample data. Hope it's similar to your problem:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:9), A=c(12,13,13,14,12,11,12,11,10),
     B=c(13,12,10,12,6,9,10,11,12),
    Type=c("F","R","F","R","W","F","R","F","R"),
    datetime=as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 01:00:00","2015-01-01 22:50:00",
                          "2015-01-02 08:30:00","2015-01-02 23:00:00",
                          "2015-01-03 14:10:00","2015-01-05 16:30:00",
                          "2015-01-05 23:00:00","2015-01-06 17:00:00",
                          "2015-01-07 23:00:00")),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Your first question is to plot the data, highlighting the first 24h after an F-point. I used dplyr and ggplot for this task.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

df %>%
    mutate(nf = cumsum(Type=="F")) %>%  # build F-to-F groups
    group_by(nf) %>%
    mutate(first24h = as.numeric((datetime-min(datetime)) < (24*3600))) %>% # find the first 24h of each F-group
    mutate(lbl=paste0(row_number(),"-",Type)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=A, y=B, label=lbl)) + 
        geom_path(aes(colour=first24h)) + scale_size(range = c(1, 2)) +
        geom_text()
```

[image]
The problem here is, that the colour only changes at some points. One thing I'm not happy with is the use of different line colors for path sections. If first24h is a discrete variable
geom_path draws two sepearate paths. That's why I defined the variable as numeric. Maybe someone can improve this?

Your second question about an interpolation can easily be solved with the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)

full.time = seq(df$datetime[1], tail(df$datetime, 1), by=600)   # new timeline with point at every 10 min
d.zoo = zoo(df[,2:3], df$datetime)        # convert to zoo object
d.full = as.data.frame(na.approx(d.zoo, xout=full.time))  # interpolate; result is also a zoo object
d.full$datetime = as.POSIXct(rownames(d.full))
```

With these two dataframes combined, you get the solution. Every F-F section is drawn in a separate plot and only the points not longer than 24h after the F-point is shown.

```
df %>%
    select(Type, datetime) %>%
    right_join(d.full, by="datetime") %>%
    mutate(Type = ifelse(is.na(Type),"",Type)) %>%
    mutate(nf = cumsum(Type=="F")) %>%
    group_by(nf) %>%
    mutate(first24h = (datetime-min(datetime)) < (24*3600)) %>%
    filter(first24h == TRUE) %>%
    mutate(lbl=paste0(row_number(),"-",Type)) %>%
    filter(first24h == 1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=A, y=B, label=Type)) + 
        geom_path() + geom_text() + facet_wrap(~ nf)
```

[image]

Comment: Markus thank you for your answer.

However form your dataset there are 4 'F' points, which means there should be 4 ggplots, each ggplot is starting from 'F' point to the next 24 hrs. However in this case you have tracked F-F.  I have added a plot in my question (from your answer) for better understanding. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the following, maybe you can get an idea from here. I recommend you to first have a variable with the time ordered (either in minutes or hours, in this example I've used hours). Let's see if it helps

```
#a data set is built as an example
N = 100
set.seed(1)
dataframe = data.frame(A = cumsum(rnorm(N)),
                       B = cumsum(rnorm(N)),
                       Type = sample(c('R','F','W'), size = N, 
                                     prob  = c(5/7,1/7,1/7), replace=T),
                       time.h = seq(0,240,length.out = N))
# here, a list with dataframes is built with the sequences
l_dfs =  lapply(which(dataframe$Type == 'F'), function(i, .data){
  transform(subset(.data[i:nrow(.data),], (time.h - time.h[1]) <= 24), 
            t0 = sprintf('t0=%4.2f', time.h[1]))
}, dataframe)

ggplot(data=do.call('rbind', l_dfs), aes(x=A, y=B, colour=Type)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_path(colour='black') + facet_wrap(~t0)
```

Comment: What did not work for you? The example I gave with simulated data? Or the example with your data? Did you tranform your time variable correctly?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't get the functioning of prob...!! It is fixed?

Comment: Parameter prob of sample is used to generate R,F,W with probabilities 5/7,1/7,1/7 respectively. It is just to get a dataset as the one you gave. The example starts in l_dfs where a list of dataframes with the sequence you ask are built.